# In InDesign Auto-size function doesn't work on linked text boxes with Data Merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I have two auto-size text boxes that are linked. Data merge field A sits in the top box, data merge field B sits in bottom text box. They are separated by a Coloumn Break set right after field A. The text boxes are auto resized correctly when holding the data merge fields but after merging, the top text box doesnt resize while the lower text box does. So one text box resizes to merged copy while the other doesnt. How can i fix this?
Thanks, JK